# cambiar de listado a cuadricula

Tags: javascript, web, programación-bajo-nivel, lista, grid

tengo una gran duda se que hay muchos preguntando lo mismo pero no encuentro nada claro en internet, quiero saber como hacer el cambio de list/grid, en mis productos, por ahora tengo esto:

```
<script>
    $('button').on('click',function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
        $('#container div').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');

    }else
        if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
        $('#container div').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    }
});</script>
```

cuando se cambia de pagina vuelve a tomar el valor inicial, (cuadriculas) y yo quiero que quede con la clase seleccionada por el usuario.
Gracias por el apoyo, la verdad estoy muy perdido.

Answer (score 1):

Como sabrás JavaScript no es un lenguaje que actúe sobre servidor, solamente sobre el cliente, por lo que para hacer estos cambios lo normal (creo) es guardar el valor que quieras mantener en una cookie que se guarda en el explorador del cliente, esto lo explican muy bien [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh). El resumen sería algo así:

```
var valorAGuardar= "value";
localStorage.setItem("NombreVariable", valorAGuardar);
```

En este punto ya hemos creado la cookie y podemos acceder a ella en cualquier momento de la siguiente manera:

```
var nombreVariable= localStorage.getItem("NombreVariable");
```

Esta variable `nombreVariable` siempre devolverá o null(si no se ha inicializado ningún valor en la cookie) o el valor guardado anteriormente.